# Can an ascending filtration be used to define completion of a vector space/ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, filtrations

Let $V: = V_0 \supseteq V_1 \supseteq V_2 \supseteq V_3 \supseteq \ldots$ be a descending filtration of a vector space $V$. Then one can define as basis of open sets given by $\{ v + V_k, v \in V, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ generating a topology on $V$. The equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in this topology is defined to the completion of $V$. Equivalently it can also be defined as an inverse limit.

Is there an equivalent way to define a completion of a vector space/ring etc using **ascending filtration?**
If $V_0' \subseteq V_1' \subseteq V_2' \subseteq \ldots$ is an ascending filtration, can one define a basis $\{ v + V_k', v \in V, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ ? How does this completion look like?

Comment: I have removed the category theory and commutative algebra tags (they don't fit here).

Answer (score 1):

In this topology, a set is open iff for every vector $v$ it also contains $v + V'_0$. So 1. the ascending filtration is not used in any way (except for the first subspace in it), 2. it is the same topology as for the constant descending filtration $V'_0 \supseteq V'_0 \supseteq V'_0 \supseteq \cdots$ and 3. the completion with respect to this topology is $V/V'_0$, so the topology is complete iff $V'_0=0$ iff the topology is trivial.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your answer. It seems my proposed topology doesn't work, but is there are other way you can impose a topology using an ascending filtration, or if I can map an ascending filtration to a descending filtration somehow? It's a very vague question, but i think every vector space with a basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots,$ admits a natural ascending filtration, $0 \subseteq \mathrm{span}(e_1) \subseteq \mathrm{span}(e_1, e_2) \subseteq $ and I am particularly interested in these.